# Getting a 'read ECONNRESET at TLSWrap.onStreamRead' in an async request function

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, econnreset

I have been able to the request npm package completely fine up until I am requesting to a specific GraphQL api. Here is my post request function below:

```
var options = {
    url: "",
    body: "",
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Sneaks-API',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Host': 'graphql.stadiumgoods.com',
      'Content-Length': 466

    }
  };

  module.exports = {
    getProductInfo: function(shoe, callback){
          options.body = '{"operationId":"sg-front/cached-a41eba558ae6325f072164477a24d3c2","variables":{"initialSearchQuery":"'+ shoe.styleID +'","initialSort":"RELEVANCE","filteringOnCategory":false,"filteringOnBrand":false,"filteringOnMensSizes":false,"filteringOnKidsSizes":false,"filteringOnWomensSizes":false,"filteringOnApparelSizes":false,"filteringOnGender":false,"filteringOnColor":false,"filteringOnPriceRange":false},"locale":"USA_USD"}'
          options.url = 'https://graphql.stadiumgoods.com/graphql'
          request.post(options,
            function (error, response, data) {    
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(json);
                    callback();
                }
            }
        );
```

However whenever I run this I keep on getting this error for some reason.

{ Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27) errno: 'ECONNRESET', code: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }

I have tried to do the same post request on Postman with the same headers and it works completely fine. Any ideas on how to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: in my limited knowledge, ECONNRESET normally occurs when you submit to a wrong socket/port (or the server restricts it to local only). Are you sure you're sending the request to the right socket/port ?

Comment: also, try with different node versions, it could be outdated http2 code.

Comment: @NarendraPatel, Were you able to fix this issue?